# How do I assign myString to an imported Python function in a bash shell?

Tags: python

I have a little homework webpage. I'm trying to automate the production of the webpage each week.

I know very little about this. Wednesday I asked about importing Python functions that I made. I think I have grasped the concept. I've tested everything in Idle. All the modules work.

In my Python shell, (I use Idle in Ubuntu), everything does what I want.

I first append the paths:

```
for i in range(0, len(pyPaths)):
    sys.path.append(pyPaths[i])
```

then import the modules:

```
from makeRBsInlineV1 import makeHTMLrbsNums
from makeCheckboxesInlineV1 import makeHTMLCBs
from makeDropdownboxesInlineV1 import makeDropdownboxes
from createhtmlTableInlineV1 import makeHTMLtable
from makeRBsInlineV2 import makeHTML_RBs
from readLinesTextboxesInlineV1 import readLinesmakeTBs
from makeThankyouPHPInlineV1 import makeThankyouPHP
```

All these modules return a text string which is a mixture of html tags + my text. It displays nicely in Firefox.

In Idle I just write, for example:

> myString = readLinesTextboxesInlineV3()

it asks me a few questions and off it goes. Afterwards, myString is ready to be put in the webpage text string.

However, in bash, I cannot write

> myString = readLinesTextboxesInlineV3()

in bash, I cannot write

> myString = input('Enter the name of the module you want.  ')

and then enter,

> readLinesTextboxesInlineV3()

because then myString is just the input text, not the function.

Each week things are different, I may need to run 2 or more of the modules, add the result strings, then write them in the webpage text string at the correct place.

I run this in a

> while True:

loop, so I can add strings from various modules.

For any given week, I don't know which module I want to use, so I make them all available.

I have a list of all the modules:

> pyFiles = ['makeCheckboxesInlineV1()', 'dropdownboxesInlineV1()',
>   'createhtmlTableInlineV1()', 'makeRBsInlineV2()',
>   'readLinesTextboxesInlineV3()', 'makeThankyouPHPInlineV1()']

How do I assign **myString** to any 1 of the modules above when I run makeWebpage.py in bash?

I tried this:

```
pyFiles = [makeHTMLCBs(), makeDropdownboxes(), makeHTMLtable(), makeHTML_RBs(), readLinesmakeTBs(), makeThankyouPHP()]
```

Declare a list of the functions. Trouble is, as soon as I do that, Python wants to run the first function immediately. I was hoping I could enter a number and run say:

```
myString = pyFiles[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you is to add `arguments` to your python script that can be added as `flag` to your command line.
This way you could call your script like the following from the shell (example):

```sh
python makeWebpage.py --module "makeCheckboxesInlineV1"
```

Python standard library provide [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module for that specific need. It's really easy to handle and transform shell argument into python variable.

I recommend that you read that [blog post](https://blog.sicara.com/perfect-python-command-line-interfaces-7d5d4efad6a2) which I found myself really useful. The part you need the most is ***What about argparse?***

Add something like this in your main:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-m', '--module', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
module = args.module # The variable module now is a String containing "makeCheckboxesInlineV1"
```